Ubuntu 24.04.01 LTS- Add HP printer CUPS server Error
I just installed Ubuntu 24.04.01 and can no longer print to my network printer. When I attempt to add a printer it is able to locate the printer. It just cannot communicate with it. I get a CUPS error when it tries to communicate with it. If I connect it to USB it works fine.
Here are printers that are found when I add a printer.


Does This answer your question?

try from http://127.0.0.1:631/

Thanks for the help. None of the above fixes it. I think #Ubuntu and #Hplip need to come up with a compatible fix. I came across this post whom is having the same issue. I ran through the steps and still have the same issue. Can print on USB just not over the network
Where can i submit this issue to Ubuntu and get notified of a fix?

Sorry the previous comments did not work for you. You did great research! This looks like a known bug from the link you provided. At the bottom of that page, you can click on Create bug report to add to that bug report.

Thanks @stumblebee ! I created the bug report. https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/2081725
fingers crossed

You now have enough reputation to Answer your own question! I strongly encourage you to do so and also answer This question Please provide both the post you found and the bug report you submitted when you answer.

BTW - If you don't feel comfortable answering the other question, that's OK. At least answer your own question.

@stumblebee done!

It turns out this is bug in the Ubuntu upgrade. Therefore I created a bug ticket

got the same issue today.  issue is because package were not installed during  24.04  upgrade.
to fix :
apt list | grep cups | grep residual   => will give you the list
Then apt install each packet (there was 3 on my side:    cups,  cups-browsed  and cups-core-drivers)

Hi @Yoconono thanks for your reply. However for me grep residual is empty.
This is what I have installed for cups-browsed
cups-browsed-tests/noble-updates,noble-updates,noble-security,noble-security 2.0.0-0ubuntu10.2 all cups-browsed/noble-updates,noble-security,now 2.0.0-0ubuntu10.2 amd64 [installed,automatic] 
And this is whats installed for core drivers
cups-core-drivers/noble-updates,noble-security,now 2.4.7-1.2ubuntu7.3 amd64 [installed,automatic] cups-filters-core-drivers/noble,now 2.0.0-0ubuntu4 amd64 [installed,automatic] 
